ExoPlayer Cache.getCachedLength always returns different size with the downloaded bytes from Downloader
I want to check whether the video is already cached or not to prevent downloading multiple-times for the same video. But when I check the cached length or cached bytes, it always returns a different size with the bytes that have been downloaded from the Downloader.
downloader.download { _, bytesDownloaded, _ ->
     Log.w(
         TAG,
         "bytesDownloaded: $bytesDownloaded"
     )
     if (bytesDownloaded >= PRE_CACHE_SIZE) downloader.cancel()
}

bytesDownloaded: 3692195
Log.w(
     TAG,
     "cachedLength: ${cache.getCachedLength(mediaItem.localConfiguration?.uri.toString(), 0 , PRE_CACHE_SIZE)}"
)

cachedLength: 1003
I've been looking for the explanation from the documentation, but nothing has explained this.
Here is the complete code
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            runCatching {
                if (cache.getCachedLength(mediaItem.localConfiguration?.uri.toString(), 0 , PRE_CACHE_SIZE) > 0) {
                    return@runCatching
                }

                downloader.download { _, bytesDownloaded, _ ->
                    Log.w(
                        TAG,
                        "bytesDownloaded: $bytesDownloaded"
                    )
                    if (bytesDownloaded >= PRE_CACHE_SIZE) downloader.cancel()
                }
            }.onFailure {
                if (it is InterruptedException) return@onFailure

                Log.d(TAG, "Cache fail for position: $position with exception: $it}")
                it.printStackTrace()
            }.onSuccess {
                Log.d(TAG, "Cache success for position: $position")
                Log.w(
                    TAG,
                    "cachedLength: ${cache.getCachedLength(mediaItem.localConfiguration?.uri.toString(), 0 , PRE_CACHE_SIZE)}"
                )
            }
        }

I'm wondering why Cache.getCachedLength always return a different size with the downloaded bytes from Downloader?
